# convert string from database to double

Tags: c#, timespan

In my program I am using a database containing a Time (string previousTimeVASN).
I have a timer to clock total seconds. i would like to display the sum of previousTimeVASN + the total seconds.

I have error showing:

> "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'" at line: double test1 = Convert.ToDouble(previousTimeVASN);

any suggestion are much appreicated.

```
private void sNbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     TabControl.SelectedIndex = 1;
     dtVASN.Tick += new EventHandler(dtVASN_Tick);
     dtVASN.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}

void dtVASN_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (swVASN.IsRunning)
     {
         TimeSpan tsVASN = swVASN.Elapsed;
         double test = tsVASN.TotalSeconds;
         double test1 = Convert.ToDouble(previousTimeVASN);
         txtVASN.Text = (test + test1).ToString(); 
     }
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `previousTimeVASN`?

Comment: What value you are getting in `previousTimeVASN` ? What is the data type of it?

Answer (score 1):

The method [`Convert.ToDouble`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todouble(v=vs.110).aspx) will throw [`FormatException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception(v=vs.110).aspx) if value is not a number in a valid format. You are getting the same here means either the value in `previousTimeVASN` is not a number or it is not in the expected format. Here is an alternate option for you to check whether the conversion is possible or not, that is, [Double.TryParse Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Converts the string representation of a number in a specified style
>   and culture-specific format to its double-precision floating-point
>   number equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion
>   succeeded or failed.

So the code can be revamped as like the following:

```
if (swVASN.IsRunning)
{
     TimeSpan tsVASN = swVASN.Elapsed;
     double test = tsVASN.TotalSeconds;
     double test1;
     Double.TryParse(previousTimeVASN, out test1);
     txtVASN.Text = (test + test1).ToString(); 
}
```

if you want to alert the user that the second number is not valid then you can use the return value of parse like the following:

```
if(Double.TryParse(previousTimeVASN, out test1))
   txtVASN.Text = (test + test1).ToString(); 
else
   txtVASN.Text = "previous Time VASN is not valid:'
```

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. I didnt notice i already saved non-number text into previousTimeVASN. after i corrected it, it works perfect. again. thank you!